# Función $watch en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Quiero implementar un contador pero mi duda es si con **$watch** de AngularJS al cambiar de pagina el contador continua a contar porque de la forma que estaba haciendo esto sin utlizar el **$watch** cuando cambio de pagina y vuelvo a la misma pagina donde se encuentra el contador veo que vuelve al estado inicia no mantiene la contage ya que como ese contador se encuentra en un controller es ejecutado nuevamente.

Me gustaria saber si con **$watch** de AngularJS mismo cambiando de pagina se mantiene el contage.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Puedes escribir algo de código para tener alguna idea de cual es el problema?

Comment: Utiliza $interval. Según las pruebas que he realizado, el contador permanece siempre, independiente si cambias la ruta. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: No olvides presionar en el check si fue la respuesta correcta.

Comment: Podrías ocupar una variable global `$rootScope`